# JSP/JSTL word wrap in a table

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a table of width 800 and one inner table within that of width 100%. The **tr td** looks like this

```
<tr><td align="right" valign= "top"><c:out value="HOUSE:  " /></td><td nowrap  align="left" valign= "top"> <c:out value='${houseBean.houseLabel}'/></td></tr>
```

Now when houseLabel goes beyond 5 values, the table grows beyond its width of 800. I tried using word-wrap to wrap around the values, but not working. Can anyone suggest a way of using wrap in JSTL/JSP. One more thing is the houseLabel values are in an arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `nowrap` attribute. It would force the table cell not to wrap its contents.

This problem is not specifically related to JSP/JSTL. The generated HTML is what counts here.